# how to map url with usernames prefixed?

Tags: python, url, flask

Suppose there is a web app name thesite.com. I need to give every user
a url of his own. For eg- if alice signs up, she gets a space of her
own at the url "alice.thesite.com".. How do I achieve this.

Thanks
Alice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a [wildcard DNS entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) to point all subdomains to your server. Then in flask, read the request host header, and pull out the subdomain (if any) that was used to access your web app:

```
host = request.host
host = host.split(':', 1)[0] # Strip off optional ':##' port number
username = None
if host.endswith('.yourdomain.com'):
    username = host.split('.', 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

By pointing all the subdomains of that domain to the same website via DNS, and then inspecting the HTTP 1.1 `Host` header to determine which user website is being viewed.